# Winsock, get host ip on specific interface

Tags: c++, windows, ip, winsock

Is there any way to get ip address of host on specific physical interface using winsock on Windows 7?
My computer is connected by ethernet cable with another pc and connected to router via wireless adapter. So how can I get only **"wireless ip"** ?, it's possible because **ipconfig** does that.

If winsock doesn't support it maybe there is win api to do such thing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need this API:

```
GetAdaptersInfo
```

Made a loop to interfaces and get IP wanted.

Comment: [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) is deprecated, use [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) instead.